Как разделить шапку документа "ОперацияСоСредствами" в 1С на две части, по 5 реквизитов в каждой?
Я создаю свою информационную базу на 1С и столкнулся с задачей, связанной с документом "ОперацияСоСредствами". В рамках этого документа необходимо рассчитывать мои траты за месяц, для чего используется 10 реквизитов.
Моя задача — разделить шапку формы элемента документа на две части: левую и правую. Каждая часть должна содержать по 5 реквизитов. Также обе части должно находиться на одном уровне высоты.
Подскажите, как можно реализовать такое разделение в 1С? Буду признателен, если вы сможете предоставить видео с пошаговым решением (если это возможно), а также подробно объясните, как это сделать.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Вам поможет книга Разработка интерфейса прикладных решений на платформе "1С:Предприятие 8".
В часности Глава 2.9. Примеры конструирования форм, подразделы:

Как и зачем объединять элементы формы в группы
Как усовершенствовать внешний вид формы - Выравнивание между группами

Вкратце, Вам нужно создать одну общую группу, с горизонтальным выравниванием, а в ней две вложенные группы, в которые как раз и разнести нужные реквизиты. В каждую группу по 5 штук.
